# Blazor Server : Manualy refresh re-rendered UI

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

In the counter example, I add a timer to increment the counter :

```cs
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
        {
            IncrementCount();
            StateHasChanged();
        };
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

This code work with Blazor WebAssembly, the counter is incremented and the UI display the new value.
But with Blazor Server, the counter is incremented (checked in debugger) but the UI isn't refresh.

How refresh manually the UI with Blazor Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Blazor WebAssembly App, which is executed under the single JavaScript UI thread available, Blazor Server App may use more than one thread with the same application, the result of which creates issues with the synchronization context.

What you need is the adjustment of the synchronization context. In terms of code you should do something like this:

```
InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()); instead of merely calling `StateHasChanged();`
```

Note that often you get this exception, depending on your code design:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The current thread is not associated with the renderer's synchronization context. Use Invoke() or InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the renderer's synchronization context when triggering rendering or modifying any state accessed during rendering.'

Hope this helps.

Comment: You only actually need `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` - there is a good explanation here https://blazor-university.com/components/multi-threaded-rendering/invokeasync/

Comment: Thank, it's work on Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly.